# unable to send email from unix shell scripting

Tags: sendmail

I'm trying to send email alert from unix shell script using 'sendmail' command, my code is as below:

```
recipients="rajkumar.soundararajan@visy.com.au,basha.kather@gmail.com,katherbasha.amanullah@techmahindra.com"
subject="DB Blocking session found!"
from="rajkumar.soundararajan@visy.com.au"

message_txt="Hi all!\n There are DB blocking session found in DB"

#echo -e "\n${output}"
if [ ! -z "$output" -a "$output" != " " ]; then

        echo "blocking session found in db!!"

#echo "DB blocking session found" | mail -s "DB BLOCKING!!" katherbasha.amanullah@techmahindra.com

#echo "DB blocking session found" | mail -s "DB BLOCKING!!" basha.kather@gmail.com

/usr/sbin/sendmail "$recipients" << EOF
subject:$subject
from:$from
$message_txt
EOF
fi
```

when executing the above code I'm getting below output but there is no email sent to anyone:

> va_manh@manhdevdb:/home/oracle/scripts$ sh db_blocking_session.sh
>   blocking session found in db!!

I found below lines in /var/log/maillog:

> Jan 28 17:52:03 manhdevdb postfix/pickup[7539]: 176D013C0BD: uid=800
>   from= Jan 28 17:52:03 manhdevdb postfix/cleanup[10861]:
>   176D013C0BD:
>   message-id=<20160128065203.176D013C0BD@manhdevdb.hosting.telstra.com>
>   Jan 28 17:52:03 manhdevdb postfix/qmgr[3591]: 176D013C0BD:
>   from=, size=406, nrcpt=3 (queue
>   active) Jan 28 17:52:33 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10865]: connect to
>   cluster6.us.messagelabs.com[216.82.242.36]: Connection timed out (port
>   25) Jan 28 17:52:33 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10863]: connect to
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.187.26]: Connection timed out (port
>   25) Jan 28 17:52:33 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10864]: connect to
>   mxmeg6.techmahindra.com[203.143.186.187]: Connection timed out (port
>   25) Jan 28 17:54:33 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10863]: 176D013C0BD:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=150, status=deferred
>   (connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[173.1
>   94.219.26]: Connection timed out) Jan 28 17:56:03 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10864]: 176D013C0BD:
>   to=, relay=none, delay=240,
>   status=deferred (connect to mxmeg2.techmahindra.c om[119.151.17.92]:
>   Connection timed out) Jan 28 17:57:08 manhdevdb postfix/smtp[10925]:
>   9EF5513C0A3: to=, relay=none,
>   delay=75276, status=deferred (connect to cluster6a.us.messagelab
>   s.com[85.158.139.103]: Connection timed out)

Kindly let me know the root cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

The connection timing out probably means your hosting provider blocks TCP/25 outbound, usually to prevent spam. You can look at relaying through a trusted provider like Amazon SES, MailGun, SendGrid, etc. Unfortunately running your own mail server these days is a constant battle.

Comment: Thanks mate. I already discussed on this with infra team. They said that there is SMTP server through which only we can send emails. Can anyone knows how to use smtp details with sendmail command?